# What is the concept of identity resolution?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#identity-resolution

> Since a tracking query uses the change tracker, EF Core will do
> identity resolution in a tracking query. When materializing an entity,
> EF Core will return the same entity instance from the change tracker
> if it's already being tracked. If the result contains the same entity
> multiple times, you get back same instance for each occurrence.
> No-tracking queries don't use the change tracker and don't do identity
> resolution. So you get back a new instance of the entity even when the
> same entity is contained in the result multiple times.

What does the following mean:

If the result contains the same entity multiple times, you get back same instance for each occurrence. No-tracking queries don't use the change tracker and don't do identity resolution. So you get back a new instance of the entity even when the same entity is contained in the result multiple times.

Comment: Do you want to know what "no-tracking" means or do you want to know what "same instance for the same entity multiple times" means?

Comment: I understand no tracking means changes to the entity will not be tracked. I'm trying trying understand what is `identity resolution` and what the following means: `If the result contains the same entity multiple times, you get back same instance for each occurrence. No-tracking queries don't use the change tracker and don't do identity resolution. So you get back a new instance of the entity even when the same entity is contained in the result multiple times`.

Answer (score 4):

A query result can contain entity instances of the same database row. This is possible when you have navigation properties and use something like `Include()` to load these navigation properties as well like this:

```
context.Posts
    .Include(it => it.Author)
    .ToList();
```

In this example, there might be posts by the same author. In that case the navigation properties of two different `Post` entities will reference the exact same instance of the `Author` entity, which is tracked by the id of the `Author` instance. The "identity resolution" will make sure that an already existing `Author` reference of the first `Post` entity will also be used for the second `Post` entity (for the same author). The `Author` navigation properties will **not** contain copies of the same database row.